# Can it be argued qualitatively that the ground state of a bound energy spectrum has zero nodes?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I am taking a 1-D system with a general potential $V(x)$ that results in a spectrum of bound energy eigenvalues. Without resorting to specific cases (such as the harmonic oscillator), how do you prove that the ground state is non-zero everywhere on the real axis? How do I prove this just from the postulates of Quantum Mechanics and the definition of a bound state?

Comment: You can argue that a wavefunction with nodes can be modified to one without and aas a result, the second derivative (i.e. the energy) will decrease, since it is less wiggly.

Comment: And how is a wavefunction with nodes modified into one without?

Comment: Duplicate [295857](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/295857/when-does-the-nth-bound-state-of-a-1-d-quantum-potential-have-n-maxima-minim).

Comment: @ferro11001: I'm talking about a mental transformation: you calculate the energy of a wiggly function, it's got a high second derivative, so the energy is high. Then consider a smooth function, it's got a small second derivative, hence the energy is smaller. The latter is a better approximation to the ground state than the former.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/304610/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/295857/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/186140/2451

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Qualitatively". So you want something less Courant-Hilbert and more seat-of-the-pants than the generic [Sturm-Liouville analysis](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/295857/when-does-the-nth-bound-state-of-a-1-d-quantum-potential-have-n-maxima-minim) summarized in Messiah vI, [Ch III, sec II.8,12](https://archive.org/stream/QuantumMechanicsVolumeI/Messiah-QuantumMechanicsVolumeI#page/n7/mode/2up).

I'll just outline a less specific/restrictive version of the [Wikipedia proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_state#1D_ground_state_has_no_nodes), basically the Feynman-certified one of [Appendix A, p 81-82, of M Cohen's 1956 Caltech PhD dissertation](http://thesis.library.caltech.edu/1007/1/Cohen_m_1956.pdf).

Without loss of generality, take the bound states to be real; and see that a state with a node at, say, *x*=0, so *ψ*(0)=0, *cannot be the ground state*, as its variational energy can always be lowered. That is,
$$
\langle E\rangle=\int dx \left ( \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \left (\frac{d\psi}{dx}\right )^2 +\psi^2 V(x) \right)
$$
is larger than the corresponding one for some continuous deformation *φ* of *ψ* which lacks a node, so *ψ* is not the ground state, after all.

You manufacture *φ* to equal |*ψ*|, except in a symmetric region [–*ε,ε*] around
*x*=0, in which we take it, instead, to be, e.g.,  *ψ(x)=ε*, suitably normalized. (The WP choice. You could make the choice smoother at the edges of the interval by more elaborate choices, without significant differences.)

[image: Cohen thesis graph]

You may then readily convince yourself that, whatever the slope of *ψ* through 0, the normalization of *φ* will exceed that of *ψ* by $O(\epsilon^3)$.

Crucially, the kinetic energy is lowered by $O(\epsilon)$,
$$
\langle T\rangle_\psi - \langle T\rangle_\phi =  \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \int^\epsilon_{-\epsilon} dx \left ( \frac{d\psi (x)}{dx}  \right ) ^2 \sim  \epsilon \frac{\hbar^2}{m} \left(\frac{d\psi}{dx} (0)\right)^2, 
$$
times some finite fraction.

$\langle V\rangle$, however, changes by  $O(\epsilon^3)$, so its contribution is subdominant, so, then, ignorable. Since $\langle E\rangle$ is lowered by  $O(\epsilon)$, your nodeful *ψ* cannot be the ground state. In practice, the nodeless *φ* may be deformed further to a smoothest form avoiding energetically expensive undulations.

- Given this result, you may now further confirm the ground state's  uniqueness. For, if it were degenerate, so, e.g., the lowest energy corresponded to *two* independent eigenstates, *ψ* and *ρ*, then *ψ(0)ρ(x)–ψ(x)ρ(0)* would have the same energy, but also a node at 0, which was just excluded.

Comment: Why do you take square of $\psi'(x)$ instead of differentiating it twice?

Comment: @Ruslan . What do you have in mind? The Sturm-Liouville surface term at infinity is ignorable. Are you asking about the detailed Messiah proof?

Comment: I mean your expression for average energy, $\langle E\rangle$. By definition, it's $\left\langle \psi\right|\hat H\left|\psi\right\rangle$, where $\hat H$ contains a second-derivative operator. But your expression doesn't agree with this definition, instead having a first derivative, which is then squared.

Comment: After you integrate by parts, you chuck the surface term at *infinity* : It is an S-L system. Again, what do you have in mind?

Comment: OK, I see what you are doing here. Was confused by such a large step taken without notice.