# How to argue on physical grounds that a function is the ground state of a Hamiltonian?

Tags: atomic-physics, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, stability, ground-state

$u_l(r) = Ar^{l+1}e^{-\kappa r}$ is provided as a solution to the radial wave equation for the Coulomb potential $$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dr^2}u_l(r)+\Bigl[\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{l(l+1)}{r^2} - \frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{r}\Bigr]u_l(r) = E_l(r)$$

I can show this solution satisfies the above differential equation and I get an expression for $E_l(r)$ which depends on $\frac{1}{(l+1)^2}$ and a bunch of constants.

How can I show or argue, on physical grounds, that $u_l(r)$ is the ground state wavefunction for $H_l$, where $H_l$ is $$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dr^2}+\Bigl[\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{l(l+1)}{r^2} - \frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{1}{r}\Bigr].$$

Answer (score 1):

Rearranging the radial equation, we can write :

$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}u-[{\frac{l(l+1)}{r^2}}-\frac{\alpha}{r}]u -\kappa^2u = 0$ , where $\kappa = \sqrt{\frac{-2mE}{\hbar^2}}$ , and    $\alpha = \frac{2me^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0\hbar^2}$

As $r \to \infty$ , The the effect of the term in the $[$  $]$  (which is the "effective Potential" ,  $V_{eff}$) becomes negligible. In this limit, the above equation reduces to $u" - \kappa^2u = 0$.   The physical expectation is that the wavefunction vanishes at $\infty$ (because we are looking for solutions representing bound states). This requires $\kappa^2$  > $0$ (and hence $\kappa$ is real) , or $E$ < $0$ , in which case, $u \to e^{-\kappa r}$ as $r \to \infty$.

In the opposite limit ($r \to 0$), we see that the term that dominates is the first term in the square bracket. In this limit, the radial equation reduces to $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}u - \frac{l(l+1)}{r^2}u = 0$. This equation has two independent solutions : $r^{l+1}$ and $r^{-l}$. We can see that only the first solution makes sense physically, as the second one diverges at $r=0$.    So, we have that $u \to r^{l+1}$ as $r \to 0$.

These two statements were derived without any assumptions, so, they must hold true for all eigensolutions of the above radial equation. So, *all* eigenstates of the radial equation must be of the form $u_n(r) = e^{-\kappa r} r^{l+1} f_n(r) $.

Now, employing the Nodal theorem (as the other answer has alluded to already), we see that   the ground state *must have zero nodes* ; we already know from above that all eigenstate have the form $u_n(r) = e^{-\kappa r} r^{l+1} f_n(r) $, where $n$ can now be understood as identifying the number of nodes in $f_n$. So, for the ground state solution, we need to find $f_0$, which is the "$f$  " with $0$ nodes that satisfies the above radial equation. And as you have found already, $f_0 = 1$.

Also, the nodal theorem can be proved :

"Feynman" version : [Can it be argued qualitatively that the ground state of a bound energy spectrum has zero nodes?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/337858/can-it-be-argued-qualitatively-that-the-ground-state-of-a-bound-energy-spectrum)

Rigorous version :  [When does the $n$th bound state of a 1-D quantum potential have $n$ maxima/minima?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/295857/when-does-the-nth-bound-state-of-a-1-d-quantum-potential-have-n-maxima-minim)

Comment: Thank you I was not aware of the nodal theorem, that's very helpful

Answer (score 0):

For one-dimensional problems (as your radial problem) there is the statement that the ground state wave function has no nodes. This does not provide a proof for a given wave function to be a ground state wave function but it clearly is an indication.